# Return false if selected Date is last Date in array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, date, datetimepicker

I have this loop which checks whether the user clicked a date that already exists in an array of arrays of reservations. My problem is that it should not warn the user if the clicked date is the last date in one of these arrays. I hope this makes sense.

```
arrayAfBookninger.forEach(function(array) {
            var lastDay = array[array.length - 1];
            array.forEach(function(dato) {
                if (startdato == moment(dato).format("YYYY-MM-DD") || slutdato == moment(dato).format("YYYY-MM-DD")) {
                    alertify.alert("Datoen er allerede booket. Vælg venligst en anden dato.");
                    $("#startdato").val("");
                    $("#slutdato").val("");
                }
                datoerMellemStartSlut.forEach(function(val) {
                    if (moment(val).format("YYYY-MM-DD") === moment(dato).format("YYYY-MM-DD")) {
                        alertify.alert("Der er bookede datoer mellem den valgte start- og slutdato. Vælg venligst en anden dato.");
                        $("#startdato").val("");
                        $("#slutdato").val("");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

If the user clicks on the 17. here, no alert should be shown.

[image]

So far I've tried saving the last day of each array in a variable, but I'm not sure how to apply this to the loop. Right now all the dates in the arrays are being compared with the startdate and enddate (slutdato) selected by the user. I also do not want to remove the Date from the array, as I need them to still be displayed with the color in the calendar.

Temporary solution:

```
if (dato == lastDay) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: please put a demo code for help  better

Comment: I managed to come up with a solution by simple returning out of the forEach loop, but I'd like to handle it with a different approach if possible. I've added the code to the post.

Comment: Aderfe ellinas eisai? Gia ton eniko tou data => dato! Theoulis!

Answer (score 1):

You could more easily check if something is in an array by using the indexOf() JavaScript array function (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).
Doing something like the below:
`if(array.indexOf(datetocheck)>-1) //it exists in the array`
This will allow you to not iterate over everything this having simpler and faster code. You can also assign the result of indexOf to a variable and have the index of the date in the array if needed.
Slightly irrelevant, but I would also suggest saving all dates using the
`new Date(dates).valueOf()` which will store them in numerical UTC timestamp which is easier to manage, and just render them of the front.